# mcts ajax question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

You are implementing an ASP.NET AJAX page. You add the following control to the page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate> ... </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You need update the contents of the `UpdatePanel` without causing
a full reload of the page. Which two actions should you perform? (Each correct answer presents part of the
solution. Choose two.)

A. Add the following control before the `UpdatePanel`. `<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnLoad="Timer1_Tick"
runat="server" Interval="3000" />`

B. Add the following control within the `UpdatePanel`. `<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnLoad="Timer1_Tick"
runat="server" Interval="3000" />`

C. Add an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` that references `Timer1`.

D. Add a `PostBackTrigger` that references `Timer1`.

Comment: Are you quizzing us?  Because my answer would be E: Don't use an UpdatePanel and just use jQuery to fetch the data you need from a JSON service and update the page accordingly.

Comment: sure no i'm trying to know the answer i did is it right or wrong , thats all

Comment: Since it's a test provided (at a price) by the company that also provides the software being tested, "right" and "wrong" are highly subjective terms.  None of the provided answers would be how I would implement such a requirement, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

You should place Timer within UpdatePanel to update contetns. So, right answers are B and C.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) "You use the Timer control to update an UpdatePanel control by including the timer **inside** the UpdatePanel control. Alternatively, you can place the timer outside the UpdatePanel control and set the timer as a trigger."

Sounds like the answer is A+C or just B.